# Python ctypes 'c_char_p' memory leak

Tags: python, c++, optimization, ctypes

I'm developing a Python library for cryptography. I wanted to optimize my library by writing the main classes in C++ with GMP. I wrote my C++ classes and I wrote the `extern` methods to use the main arithmetic operations: addition, subtraction, etc... These methods returns the results as char* to avoid cast problems. I built the DLL of my library and I declared the methods in a Python wrapper with ctypes. I noticed that after each arithmetic operation with huge numbers the memory grew exponentially. I was looking for problems in my C++ implementation, but there were no problems thanks to the C++ garbage collector. I was looking for a possible solution, so I discovered that I had to implement a C++ method to free up memory of the string created by the DLL. So I wrote this simple method:

```
extern "C" {

    __declspec(dllexport) void free_memory(char * n)
    {
        free(n);
    }
    ...
}
```

I implemented this code in the Python wrapper to free up the memory allocated by the DLL:

```
import os
import ctypes

DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
NUMERIC = ctypes.CDLL(DIR_PATH + "/numeric.dll")
...
NUMERIC.free_memory.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
NUMERIC.free_memory.restype = None

def void_cast(n):
    a = ctypes.cast(n, ctypes.c_char_p)
    res = ctypes.c_char_p(a.value)
    NUMERIC.free_memory(a)
    return res
```

So with `res = ctypes.c_char_p (a.value)` I create a new variable that no longer points to `a`. This way I correctly delete `a` using the DLL method, but I still have memory leak problems. It is as if the Python garbage collector does not free up correctly the memory of strings of type `c_char_p`. In the previous implementation I used only Python and the `gmpy2` library, so all the numbers were converted to `mpz` or `mpq`. I tested the memory consumption using the `memory_profiler` package. I created 40 objects of type projective point, defined on an elliptical curve, and I calculated the products `i*P`, with`i` from 1 to 40. With `gmpy2` about 70MB in total were used. Instead, using ctypes with the classes in C++ the consumption of the memory rose to 1.5GB. It's obvious that there is something wrong, especially when only the base classes that deal with arithmetic operations change. How can I properly free the memory without having memory leak problems?
I put an example of `extern` method for calculating an arithmetic operation, but I have already checked that the problem lies only in correctly freeing the memory via the`free_memory` function and reassigning the string so that the garbage collector of Python will free the string when needed.

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) const char* rat_add(const char * n, const char * m)
    {
        return (RationalNum(n) + RationalNum(m)).getValue();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

PS: Clearly in C++ I correctly implemented the destructor method to free up the space of the `mpz_t` and `mpq_t` objects created.

Comment: What do you mean with "C++ garbage collector"? C++ does not have a garbage collector.

Comment: How do you use `rat_add` from python? It probably allocates memory for the string that is returned by `getValue()`, and this memory might not be freed correctly.

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @pschill Unfortunately I cannot give a minimal example since the classes have more than a thousand lines due to the verbosity of the operators in C ++ (I created about 5/6 overloads for each operator for different types for reasons of practicality of use). I use `rat_add` in the `__add__` method of the `RNum` class that I created by writing `x = dll.NUMERIC.rat_add (self.n, parse (other)); return RNum (dll.void_cast (x))` (the semicolon is only here because of the comment). The `parse` function converts the `other` parameter to a `c_char_p` if it isn't already.

Comment: Then the `void_cast` function took care of casting from `c_void_p` to `c_char_p` and eliminating the string via `free_memory`, as I wrote in the post.
Anyway, I thought that C++ had a garbage collector otherwise how is it possible that if I run the code from C ++ with huge numbers there is no memory leak, while the same code called by Python have a memory leak?

Comment: C++ has manual memory management. This means that for each `new`, there must be a corresponding `delete` (and for each `malloc` there must be a corresponding `free`). There are wrapper classes, that automatically do this for you via constructor/destructor, for example, `std::string` and `std::vector`. This is still called manual memory management and not garbage collection.

Comment: Either `rat_add` or `RationalNum` has a memory problem: `RationalNum(n) + RationalNum(m)` creates three temporary `RationalNum` objects: One for `n`, one for `m`, one for the addition result. All three objects are destroyed when `rat_add` returns. Now there are 2 possibilities: (1) The `RationalNum` destructor frees its string. In that case, `rat_add` is buggy because it returns a pointer to freed memory. (2) The `RationalNum` destructor does not free the string. In that case, the temporaries for `n` and `m` leak, even if you manually destroy the addition result from Python via `void_cast`.

Comment: @pschill The `RationalNum` class does not free its string. In particular, `RationalNum` has only one attribute of type `mpq_t`. Basically it's a wrapper to use `mpq_t` and do all the operations between `mpq_t` numbers without calling `mpq_init`, `mpq_set`, etc ... In the destructor I call `mpq_clear`. Since I didn't create a new object with `new`, technically when closing the` rat_add` function, the two created objects should be destroyed and so it seems to be going when I execute the code on C++.

Comment: `mpq_init` and `mpq_clear` is like `new` and `delete`. If your destructor calls `mpq_clear` and you implemented proper copy/move constructor/assignment, everything should be fine. Can you show us the `RationalNum` code? Without the code, everything is just guessing.

Comment: @pschill Do you want to show nearly 1200 line of codes? Anyway, I've already tried to explicitly call the `RationalNum` destructor by creating the operands via `new`. The impact on Python is the same and both lead to a memory leak. The only thing that creates memory is the result of the operation as a string.

Comment: @pschill If I implement `void_cast` by writing `res = a.value` then there is no memory leak, but in doing so I no longer have the reference to `a` after the `free_memory` and in `res` random hexadecimal values can appear. Instead, by creating a new `c_char_p` object by doing `res = ctypes.c_char_p (a.value)`, the memory of `a` is freed via the `free_memory` function, but the memory of `res` is not freed from Python. It's as if it kept it in the cache. Is it possible for ctypes to cache c_char_p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
res = ctypes.c_char_p(a.value)
```

This creates a copy of `a.value` and sets `res` to a `c_char_p` that points to the copy. However, Python does not do memory management for `ctypes` pointers, so the copy will be leaked!

The leak should be fixed if you replace above line with:

```
res = bytes(memoryview(a.value))
```

This also creates a copy, but `res` will be a real Python object.

Comment: Just as I assumed ... As I already wrote, I had to write that line of code since the `free_memory` also deleted the reference in `res`. I'll fix it! Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Okay, I can't prove that this instruction solves the problem since I realized that the problem lies in the pow operation. When I calculate `pow(47, 300 * i)`, for i growing, a lot of space is wasted on C++ which is not freed. If I do it on Python as `pow(mpz (47), mpz(300) * i)`, the space occupied is practically constant and less than 100MB. I'll have to look if it's possible to fix the problem on C++. Thanks anyway for your help.